# Google gsa - add custom field on keymatches

Tags: google-search-appliance

Is it possible to add a custom field on google gsa keymatches? I need one more, besides word, link, and description

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add custom fields but I have seen some people set the "Title/Description" to be multi-valued by having a delimiter.

i.e.  Title|Category|Description

Then, in your display logic you have to break apart the value.

The person maintaining the Keymatches has to be diligent to handle it well.